# Rebinding this on angular callback from inside link funtion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive similar to this this:

```
app.directive('example', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      callback: '&'
    },
    template: '<span ng-click="example.callback()">Click Me</span>',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'example',
    controller: function() {
      this.counter = 0;

      this.incrementCount = function() {
        this.counter++;
      };

      this.getCount = function() {
        return this.counter;
      };
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
      var oldCallback = scope.callback;
      ctrl.callback = function() {
        console.log(ctrl);
        return oldCallback.call(ctrl); // I want to be able to use `this` as the controller to access the API from within the callback
      };
    }
  };
});
```

with a controller

```
app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", function(s) {
  s.callback = function() {
    this.incrementCount();
    console.log("Value: " + this.getCount());
  };
}]);
```

And view

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <example callback="callback()"></example>
  </div>
</div>
```

[(codepen)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akRaPo)

When I log ctrl in within the ctrl.callback in the link function it logs the example controller as I expect but when oldCallback is called, it doesn't get ctrl rebound to `this` as I want. Is there any way to access the API defined in the directive's controller from within the callback on the scope while still using an isolate scope for the directive?

Comment: Why use the link function at all? You should be able to pass $scope into the controller and access $scope.callback from there.

Comment: In the actual directive I'm using link to decorate the callback to return true unless it explicitly returns false for purposes of flow control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the directives controller out through the callback. e.g.

example html

```
<span ng-click="example.callback({$exampleCtrl:example})">Click Me</span>
```

index html

```
<example callback="callback($exampleCtrl)"></example>
```

controller

```
$scope.callback = function($exampleCtrl) {
    $exampleCtrl.incrementCount();
    console.log("Value: " + $exampleCtrl.getCount());
};
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzqqzV

Also note that `bindToController` is only supported in AngularJs 1.3+ and your code pen was using 1.2

Comment: Great, this does exactly what I need. I had initially tried passing an argument through the template but I guess I had the syntax wrong.

Comment: yeah the syntax for this is a bit weird. but it works